# Show Sympy Expression using Pylatex

Tags: python, sympy, pylatex

I am trying to display sympy expression using pylatex and generate pdf ultimately. See below for a simple example. The code does not display the expression correctly.

```
from pylatex import Document
import sympy as sp

W,L=sp.symbols('W L')
w,l=3,10
expr=(W*(L**2))/8

doc=Document()
doc.append(expr)
doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False,compiler='pdfLaTeX',filepath=file)
```

Comment: Did you try `from sympy import latex` then `doc.append(latex(expr))`?

Comment: I did but it did not work. My ultimate goal is to create a pdf that contains mathematical expression using Sympy and be nicely printed. My search led me to use Pylatex but I cannot figure out how to use both of them together.

Answer (score 0):

An example of creating a latex doc from python is given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pylatex-module-in-python/). Search for "Create a Pylatex document" on the page.

Comment: Thanks your answer. However, the Pylatex documentation does not mention anything about Sympy. It is not clear to me how can I force Pylatex to display a Sympy expression in the code. Pylatex has math module and I tried to use it to display sympy but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your code is 'not Latex'.

expr=(W*(L**2))/8

You should turn to latex with use Sympy latex:

> So expr0=W*(L**2)/8

> expr=latex(expr0, itex=True)

[out] \frac{L^{2} W}{8}

Also don't forget you can tex editor for this doc process.(i don't know exact) look at "Miktex"